# Why has the camera on my iphone stopped working?

Tags: iphone, software-update, camera, space

Tthe camera on my phone (iPhone 6S+) has stopped working. I thought it was due to lack of space (indeed, I couldn't even press the button and take a blank photo). That was for one side of the camera (they are two - selfie and the other side). (I had no space at that point, and nothing really I could do - installation of apps, etc.)

I then cleared some space, and one of the sides cleared up, and I could take photos again. But that was for a short time, at some point it stopped working again, even though the space hasn't become close to 0.

I read about it, and since then, have updated iOS, and even wiped the phone and restarted with a backup from iCloud. The camera is still not working.

While it could be a hardware problem, I highly suspect that this is not the case, at least for the selfie side of the camera. How do I confirm it, and what is there left to try?

Comment: Wipe the phone.  Restore as new.  Don't restore a backup.  Does the camera work now?

Comment: Ditto what @MarcWilson said.  You have a backup and you said you “cleared some space and things cleared up.”  Wipe it completely and see if you can take pictures.  If you can, you have your answer.

Comment: @MarcWilson no, the camera doesn't work. if it were a hardware problem, I would expect the Camera app button to be clickable but taking blank black photos. This is not the case - the button is not clickable. Is that indicative of anything fixable?

Comment: Maybe you can access some log files and see which errors or warnings the OS produces

Comment: @johk95 how do I access such log files? I didn't know Apple transparently provides access to such files, or are you suggesting I could do it if I jailbreak the phone?

Comment: @kloop try to see what you can find in Settings -> Privacy -> Analytics -> Analysis Data. Otherwise you need a Mac with Xcode